# cant get the proper output from the mysql php private chat room

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am new in web developing field. And this is a basic private chat room which i implemented.

This is the **logs.php** file which displays output to the user.

```
<?php
    require 'dbConnect.php';

   $rec=$_POST['live'];  //receive active member's name from jquery function

   $query2="SELECT * FROM chatlog WHERE receiver = 'all' OR receiver ='".$rec." '   ORDER BY id DESC";


    $result=mysql_query($query2);

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo '<span class="user">'.$row['user'].'</span>'  ."  :"." ".$row['Message']."<br/>";

     } ?>
```

This is jquery function in which i send active user's user name to receive  his logs using ajax.

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var x=$('#userx').text(); // get active user's name 

$.ajax({cache:false});

setInterval(function() {

    $('#con_mess').load('logs.php',{live:x}); },2000);  
});
```

records belonging to query part
" chatlog WHERE receiver = 'all' " are only displyed.

```
 receiver = ' " .$rec. "  ' //this part doesn't work even in a separate query.
```

Private messages  which mentions receivers name  are  not displayed.

My mysql chatlog table structure is.

```
chatlogs(id,user,receiver,Message)
```

Comment: can you please first echo and exit your query and check its returns data on phpmyadmin or not?

Comment: it returns a part of the answer only....when i use " SELECT * FROM chatlog  receiver ='  ".$rec."   '   ORDER BY id DESC " for the query it doesn't return anything..

Comment: You mean you get empty data right ? if yes then how can you get data in fetch_array ?